# Applying filters on outputted HTML for AngularJS

Tags: filter, escaping, angularjs

I created 2 filters in AngularJS `autolink` and `nl2br`.

**`autolink`:** converts a URL string to an `<a>` tag with the attributes `rel="nofollow" target="_blank"`. I tried using ngSanitize with the linky filter, but it doesn't add the 2 attributes above to it, nor does it provide a way to do it with the exising API.

**`nl2br`:** converts new lines to `<br>` tags.

I want to apply these 2 filters to `{{ comment }}` using `{{ comment | autolink | nl2br }}` in my HTML, but the filters are applied before AngularJS does the HTML escaping which results in the `<a>` and `<br>` to be escaped as well. Basically, I want to apply the filters **after** the escaping took place.

Is there a way to do this with AngularJS?

Answer (score 13):

If you have a standard interpolation in your HTML, Angular will escape it:

```
<div> {{ var | filter1 | filter2 }} </div>
```

The result of the whole expression will be escaped.

What you want is `ng-bind-html-unsafe` [(docs here)](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angBindHtmlUnsafe). You can expression basically the same thing as above as:

```
<div ng-bind-html-unsafe='var | filter1 | filter2'></div>
```

Now the result of the expression won't be sanitized, and will be inserted as the contents of the div.

**EDIT:** Note that there's also [`ng-bind-html`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize.directive%3angBindHtml), which will still produce HTML, but will sanitize it first ([`$sanitize` docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize.%24sanitize)).

`ng-bind-html` lives in the `ngSanitize` module, so you'll have to make sure that you've declared it as a dependency in your `angular.module` call.

Comment: But I want the comment, in my case, to be escaped; with the 2 filters applied after the escaping.

Comment: Ah, then use `ng-bind-html` instead of `ng-bing-html-unsafe`. I've added that to the answer.

Comment: I did do that as stated in my original post. But I want everything escaped THEN apply my filters. `ng-bind-html` will safely escape some HTML and will leave some basic html tags alone. Also with `ng-bind-html`, it will remove the `href` attribute that I am defining with my `autolink` filter.

Comment: `ng-bind-html` is different from using curly braces. See http://jsfiddle.net/GqNxT/ - the href isn't stripped.

Comment: You could also inject the `$sanitize` service into your controller, set `$scope.sanitizedComment = $sanitize($scope.comment)` and then apply the filters to the pre-sanitized comment.

Comment: "then apply the filters to the pre-sanitized comment" It's still not doing what I want. I want to apply the filters to the post-sanitized comment. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Ok, last try, as I think you're misunderstanding me. (1) have some data in `$scope.comment`. (2). inject `$sanitize` and sanitize just the comment `$scope.sanitizedComment = $sanitize(@scope.comment)`. (3) Use `sanitizedComment` in your HTML `<div ng-bind-html-unsafe='sanitizedComment | autolink | nl2br></div>`. That way you only sanitize the comment, then the filters are applied __unsafely__, as-is, with ng-bind-html-unsafe.